# Ошибка при выборке существующих пользователей из таблицы

Tags: php

```
    $data = $_POST;

if (isset($_POST['dosignup'])) {

$errors = array();
if (trim($data['regname']) == '') {
    $errors[] = "Введите логин";
}
if ($data['regpass'] == '') {
    $errors[] = "Введите пароль";
}
if (trim($data['regemail']) == '') {
    $errors[] = "Введите емаил";
}

$user = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = '$data[regname]' OR email='$data[regemail]'";
$res = $connect->query($user);
$sel = mysqli_num_rows($res);
if($sel > 0){
    echo "User is registered ";
}else{
if (empty($errors)) {
    $regname = $data['regname'];
    $regpass = password_hash($data['regpass'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $regemail = $data['regemail'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(id,login,email,password) VALUES (NULL,'$regname','$regemail','$regpass')";
    $connect->query($sql);

}else{
echo "<div id='errors' style='color:red;'>".array_shift($errors)."</div>";
}}}
?>


<?php $connect->close();


 ?>
```

Выдает ошибку Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given
Не понимаю где оно там нашло булевой тип, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: res  имеет mixed тип, если ошибка соединения, может и false

Comment: Спасибо помогла статья, я не выбрал базу данных

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Не хватало строки

```
mysqli_select_db($connect, $selectdb);
```